# Integracion de MercadoPago

Tags: javascript, ajax, mercadopago

alguien pudo utilizar MercadoPago mediante la llamada a las api que proporcionan ellos(solo desde el front, sin utilizar el SDK), por que estoy teniendo problemas para hacerlo a continuacion dejo el code que estoy usando al ingresar los datos mediante un form

```
function pagarMercadoPago() {
    var pagar = $("#txt-monto-pagar").val();
    alert("El monto a pagar es" + " " + "$" + pagar);
    var token = "https://apiinternos.movistar.com.ar//telefonica/api/mercadopago/empresas/oauth/token";
    var url = "https://apiinternos.movistar.com.ar//telefonica/api/mercadopago/empresas/checkout/preferences?=token";
  $.ajax({
        type: POST,
        url: url,
        contentType: application / json,
        beforeSend() {
            MostrarAlert("Tus datos estan siendo prosesados", true)
        },
        success(response) {
            alert("tu operacion ha sido exitosa")
        },
        data: {
                                             
            },
            "BackUrls":
            {
               
            },
         
        },
        error() {
            MostrarAlert("Ha ocurrido un error al procesar tus datos", false)
        }

    })
  

}
```

Comment: Nunca he utilizado esta API, pero puedo ver que no utilizas la variable `token` en ningún lugar, que `contentType` no es una cadena de texto (creo que debería ser igual a `"application/json"`), y también me extraña que token sea una URL en vez de una cadena aleatoria.

Comment: Gracias por la observacion,a mi tmb me extraño lo de la URL para el token, pero ellos me dicen que se usa asi, ahi le pase la variable token a  la variable url

Comment: Ahora solo estás añadiendo el texto `token` al final de la URL. Para pasarle la variable a la URL, debería ser _algo así_: `var url = '[...]/preferences?=' + token;`.

Comment: Donde está la documentación de esa API?

Comment: No estás utilizando esto, no? https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/guides/sdks/official/js/

Comment: Según ellos no es necesario la integración del SDK, con el llamado a las URL, se puede realizar solo desde el front.